# How to split the view in 2 columns with css

Tags: html, css

I tried to build a split view with css, I have built a demo to illustrate my idea.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRgbpN

I want to have the `column 1` and `column 2`, both of them will have an independent scoll bar so that I can scroll them sperately. I try with the css grid and I found I cannot set the height of `column 1` and `column 2` to be the same height as the `container`. If I can do that, I maybe could use `overflow: scroll` to make that happened. But I try with tons of solutions and I found out I cannot set the height: 100% work. What I have done wrong? Is there any better solution to solve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` if you want navi and content to also fill the entire width of your container.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px dotted red;
  display: flex;
}

.navi, .content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* flex: 1 */
}

.navi {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
}

.content {
  border: 3px dotted yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navi">
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Could you tell me try it doesn't work with css grid?

Comment: Change your `grid-template-column` declaration to `grid-template-rows: 1fr` and then add `grid-column: 1;` to your navi class and `grid-column: 2;` to your content class. Finally, give both a `overflow-y: scroll;` declaration.